# change color based on the string value

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to change the primary color based on a string value , meaning if the string value is this then main color = this , else main color =that color
i have a color.dart file with this code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';

Color mainColor = Color(0xfff04592);
```

and i have a string value stored in a class.

what i dont understand is how can i use conditional statement "if" in the colors.dart file ?
like this :

```
if (value=='asd') 
{mainColor = Color(0xfff04592);}
else
{mainColor = Color(0xfff09245);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ternary operator for assigning different colors like this:

```
Color mainColor = value == 'asd' ? Color(0xfff04592) : Color(0xfff09245);
```

Comment: What if there is more then one String?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable to store actual state for condition:

```dart
String value = 'default';

Color mainColor = value == 'default' ? Colors.green : Colors.red;
```

Answer (score 1):

i think its bette rto do in material app, you can do...

```
primaryColor: value == 'asd' ? colorOne : colorTwo
```

you can define your `colorOne` and `colorTwo` somewhere else